# Python: Using delimiter to write into specific columns of csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an input text file with each line in the format

```
Line[X]: [AAA] [BBB] [CCC] :1234
```

I would like to use "**:**" as delimiter and write to each column into a excel file. I have tried the following code but not sure if this is the right approach. Any inputs are highly appreciated.

```
import csv
Text_File = open("some_text_file.txt", "w+")
csv_results = open ("Results.csv", 'w')

for eachline in Text_File:
    csv_results.writer(Text_File, delimiter ='**:**',quotechar='**:**', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Read the PyDocs at https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html regarding CSV writing.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
txt = open("some_text_file.txt", "w+")
csv_results = open ("Results.csv", 'w')
text_reader = reader(txt)

#this delimiter is for your output file to be read by excel
csv_results.writer(Text_File, delimiter =',')

for line in txt:
    split_line = line.split(":")
    csv_results.writerow(split_line)


txt.close()
csv_results.close()
```

This **should** do what you want it to. If you want to remove the spaces on either side of the second column, you can probably use regex for that.

Comment: My input is a text file with the following format:
Line[X]: [AAA] [BBB] [CCC] :1234

My output should be a excel file with Line[X] in column1,  [AAA] [BBB] [CCC] in column2 and 1234 in column3 i.e COLON (:) seperated string appearing in each column of the excel file

Comment: Hey, see if this works. The only manual work you should have to do is opening the .csv in excel and then saving it as a .xls. There's no standard library, as far as I know, for dealing with .xls files within Python. @juggernaut

Comment: txt should be opened as read "r", csv_results as write binary "wb". Comma is the default delimiter but there is also dialect=csv.excel

Comment: @CameronBlandford - There is a python excel writer, xlwt avialable from pypi https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt/0.7.5